# Two models pointing to the same table .NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

New to .NET core here. Trying to create a model structure to accommodate the following:

- A single table, jobs, with a jsonb column in postgres
- Multiple types of jobs, each of which will have a certain 'type' column string
- Each job type will have it's own validation on the json column

Right now, I have two models. JobsServer.Models.Job and JobsServer.Models.SubJobCategory.SpecificJob. The look like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace JobsServer.Models
{
  [Table("jobs")]
  public class Job
  {
    [Column("id"), Key, Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    [Column("type"), Required]
    public string Type {get; set;}
    [Column("domain"), Required]
    public string Domain {get; set;}
    [Column("status"), Required]
    public string Status {get; set;}
    [Column("data", TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public string Data {get; set;}

    [Column("rescheduled_from_id")]
    public int RescheduledFromId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("RescheduledFromId")]
    public Job RescheduledFrom {get; set;}

    [Column("parent_job_id")]
    public int ParentJobId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("ParentJobId")]
    public Job ParentJob {get; set;}

  }

}


using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

using JobsServer.Models;

namespace JobsServer.Models.SubJobCategory
{
  [Table("jobs")]
  public class SpecificJob
  {
    [Column("id"), Key, Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    [Column("type"), Required]
    public string Type {get; set;}
    [Column("domain"), Required]
    public string Domain {get; set;}
    [Column("status"), Required]
    public string Status {get; set;}
    [Column("data", TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public string Data {get; set;}

    [Column("rescheduled_from_id")]
    public int RescheduledFromId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("RescheduledFromId")]
    public Job RescheduledFrom {get; set;}

    [Column("parent_job_id")]
    public int ParentJobId {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("ParentJobId")]
    public Job ParentJob {get; set;}

  }

}
```

I then have a job context that looks like this:

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

using JobsServer.Models;

```
namespace JobsServer.Contexts
{
  public class JobContext : DbContext
  {
    public JobContext(DbContextOptions<JobContext> options) : base(options)
    {}

    public DbSet<Job> Jobs {get; set;}
    public DbSet<JobsServer.Models.SubJobCategory.SpecificJob> SpecificJob {get; set;}
  }
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
Cannot use table 'jobs' for entity type 'Job' since it is being used for entity type 'SpecificJob' and there is no relationship between their primary keys.
```

I'm probably going about this the wrong way. I'm coming from a ruby on rails and primarily elixir background, where I can accomplish what I'm trying to do here.

Essentially, if a user submits a post for creating a SpecificJob, I plan to set type to 'specific_job' and then validate the data json to match a certain format. There will be multiple types of jobs, of course, but the above is a simplified version to test the architecture.

Any assistance or ideas appreciated.

Comment: have you tried inheritance? create one class and extend it twice. it is supposed to do exactly this

Comment: check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EF pattern you are likely looking for is Table-per-Hierarchy, where you use inheritance to differentiate types of jobs, represented in a single job table with a discriminator. ("Type")

You should find all you need here:
https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

Comment: I believe it's noteworthy to add that TPH is currently the only available solution in EF Core, and Table Per Type is not officially supported yet.

Comment: Really? ugh that is a bit of a bummer. I've only been tinkering with Core. Hopefully it's not too long before TPT is supported. I don't use inheritance much at all (I favor composition) but where I do, it's typically TPT.